# How to publish Github repository

Tags: macos, github

I need to publish a Github repository from a directory on my computer.

I added, committed, and pushed the origin master of the files I wanted to publish from the root directory of my project. By that, I mean I clicked the "create a new repository" button and typed all the git commands in my terminal while in the project directory I want to publish as my repository. For a list of the commands I used, see the below section labeled "Code."

I saw no errors during the terminal commands. When I finished, all I saw in my repository was the README.md file and nothing else.

I tried to check at my terminal to see if my login name matched the Github username of the target repository. But I didn't see any commands for checking the login name at the terminal.

**OS/config**: Using OS X 10.10.5 (Yosemite) on MacBook Air

#### Code

I tried this...

```
git init
git add README.md # This is the problem. (See my answer below.) Should be "git add ."
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/"username"/"repository".git
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @banana: Using OS X 10.10.5 (Yosemite) on a MacBook Air

Comment: Some git basic command: https://sonnguyen.ws/git-how-to/

Comment: Did you add, commit, and push origin master the files you wanted to publish?

Comment: @AndrewFan: Yes, that process was what I was trying to describe in the second paragraph of the question. I saw no errors in any of those steps.

Comment: Check out [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/). I recommend using the command line for all your git commands, but SourceTree is great for visualizing everything, particularly when you're starting out. It will give you a better picture of what's going on and allow you to modify things if you get stuck on the command line.

Comment: Get the status of your local repository by entering git status. And see whether the files added or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres a basic push to GitHub, What kind of errors are you getting?

> create a new repository on the command line
>
> ```
> git init
> git add .      //This will add everything in the directory
> git commit -m "first commit"
> git remote add origin https://github.com/"username"/"repository".git
> git push -u origin master
> ```
>
> …or push an existing repository from the command line
>
> ```
> git remote add origin https://github.com/"username"/"repository".git
> git push -u origin master
> ```

Comment: Those are the steps I followed (described in paragraph two of the question). I saw no errors. Just no files were uploaded to the repo.

Comment: `git add .` You tried this one specifically? Github on inital repo create will tell you to run `git add README.md`

Comment: Now I'm getting the error... "fatal: remote origin already exists." when I attempt the command: `git remote add origin https://github.com/"username"/"repository".git`

Comment: just delete the repo you made remake a new one on github then change the values `username` and `repository` to the values you need. without quotes of course. your close haha

Answer (score 0):

Here is what solved the problem for me...

That second git command line should be `git add .` not `git add README.md`. The `.` adds all the files in the directory, as mentioned by the accepted answer.

#### Code

Solution

```
git init
git add .  # This was the key line to change from what was tried in the question.
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/username/repository
git push -u origin master
```