# Command to publish new local repository to GitHub without manually creating a new repository in GitHub?

Tags: git, github, github-desktop

**Note:** This is not a duplicate of these questions:
[Create a new GitHub repository](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37330075/9636037)
[How to publish Github repository](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33226910/9636037)

I could see that "GitHub Desktop" has the feature to publish a new local repository into GitHub without manually create a new repository in GitHub.

[image]

How can I achieve the same using commands?

In other words, how to publish a new repository without opening a browser?

From this [article](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line), we see the requirement to use the browser for Step 1 and Step 7.

Is this possible **only for GitHub Desktop** since it is a first-party application?

**P.S:** Looking for a solution without using GitHub APIs. Any git command is fine.

Comment: You can't do this through git, but can through the GitHub API: https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/repos#create-a-repository-for-the-authenticated-user

Comment: @jonrsharpe, Thanks for the confirmation. 
I am aware of the GitHub API. 
Just wanted to make sure that was the only approach.
Happy to accept this as an answer if you could post it as one.

Comment: You can use [`hub`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35125094/7976758) or [`gh`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61460192/7976758) command line utilities (that are convenient wrappers over Github API). https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+create+repository+command+line